# Check if input date is in given range

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with a simple input type. I'm trying to define a function to check if the date is no more than 6 months older compared to date provided by the input type. 
I know i have to convert the String provided by the input in a Date object to make this comparison and then work on get methods of Date object, but i can't figure out how to do this.

Current code:

```
$scope.compareDates = function(d1) {
        d1 = new Date(d1); //convert String into date Object                
        var d = new Date(); // today date           
        d.setYear(d.getFullYear());
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 6);           

        if(d1 > d ) {
            console.log("ok");
        } else {
            console.log("error");               
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I'm sorry, i forgot to add my input. Here it is:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="gg/mm/aaaa" ng-model="sStartDate" ng-change="change()">
```

Angular Controller:

```
$scope.sStartDate = '';

$scope.change = function(){

    var startDt = $scope.sStartDate;
    $scope.compareDates(startDt);

}
```

Comment: Please provide your input String, Are you trying to compare your input with today minus 6 months?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: Is your Date string that is being imputted an actual format the browser understands? what is `gg/mm/aaaa`?

Comment: @epascarello Italian for Day, Month, Year?

Comment: @BillWoodger Exactly, italian for Day/Month and Year. Yeah, Date conversion works fine, i used that String converted to Date for other things and didn't have any problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your code correctly, your date format is days/month/year which is not valid format. You need to swap the month and days.

```
var parts = d1.split(),
    dateStr = parts[1] + "/" + parts[0] + "/" parts[2],
    d1 = new Date(d1),
    d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 6);
if(d1 > d ) {
    console.log("ok");
} else {
    console.log("error");               
}
```

Comment: Good to see someone actually reads the details, rather than answers blindly :-)

Comment: Turns out this was the problem, after implementing your code i changed the if statement d1.getTime() and d.getTime() and it works! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

What's about using `d.getTime()`?

```
$scope.compareDates = function(d1){
        d1 = new Date(d1); //convert String into date Object                
        var d = new Date(); // today date           
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 6);           

        if(d1.getTime() > d.getTime() ) {
            console.log("ok");
        } else {
            console.log("error");                
        }
    }
```

Regards.

Comment: @MoshFeu Not working unfortunatly. For example, if in my input i write 01/11/2015 the console prints "error" even if that date is less than 6 months ago. Seems like it always prints "error" if year is different than current one (2016), and always prints "ok" if year = 2016.

Comment: @steiacopi First, this is not the fault to MoshFeu, he just edited the post to correct quote. Secondly, you need to check the string input `d1`, by default date string is in US format (MM/dd/yyyy) and not (dd/MM/YYYY). Test again the code with in input `"11/01/2015"`instead of `"01/11/2015"`

Answer (score 0):

I used momentjs for this in our app. It makes this process very easy and smooth.

```
// is6MonthsOld will be a boolean value
var is6MonthsOld = moment(d1).isBefore(moment().subtract(6, 'months'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but unfortunatly i can't use momentsJs, i can't use anything bar pure AngularJs/Javascript/Jquery, i'm working on a custom framework :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing `dates` and not `time`, make sure to reset time in your date object using `d1.setHours(0,0,0,0)`.

When you do `new Date()`, output is a `datetime` object, but when you do `new Date(2015,6,19)`, only date is assigned and time is set to `00:00:00`.

Following code depicts the same:

```js
function compareDates(d1,d2){
  return +d2 > +d1;
}

function compareDatesWithHoursReset(d1,d2){
  d1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  d2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  return +d2 > +d1;
}

function main(){
  var d1 = new Date();
  var d2 = new Date(2015, 6, 19);
  d1.setMonth(d1.getMonth() - 6)
  
  console.log(d1);
  console.log(d2);
  
  console.log(compareDates(d2,d1))
  console.log(compareDatesWithHoursReset(d2,d1))
}

main();
```